# google App engine datastore via JPA and JDO

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

What jar are files needed for Google App engine datastore via JPA and JDO?

Comment: Reading the docs for any system is something you should do before trying to use it.

Answer (score 3):

The Google App Engine platform provides Java persistence (JDO or JPA) to its BigTable datastore using the [datanucleus-appengine](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/) plugin. This plugin contains the JARs you're looking for.